# How to solve for x when observing through a for loop?

Tags: java, variables, if-statement, for-loop, integer

Assume x is an integer and has been initialized to some value. Consider the code

```
for (int a = 1; a < 20; a++)
    if (x < 0)
        x = a;
```

Which statement will have the same effect on the value of x?

**a.**`if (x < 0) x = 1;`

**b.**`if (x < 20) x = 19;`

**c.**`if (x < 0) x = 19;`

**d.**`if (x < 20) x = 20;`

**e.**`x = 1;`

For this problem, I was a little confused on what the question was asking because the answer was not what I was expecting.

I chose answer choice **b.**`if (x < 20) x = 19;` because 19 is less than 20 and the other answer choices are false when plugging into 'x'. The answer to this question is actually **a.**`if (x < 0) x = 1;`. I am confused on why answer choice **a.** is the answer.

Comment: Where is x defined? Is x defined as 0?

Comment: the value of x is not given.

Comment: Oh i didnt see the first line of text.

Comment: My point of confusion is that I am not exactly sure what the question is asking, I may be wrong in what I did to attempt to complete the problem.

Comment: Well if x has been initialized to 5 (or anything greater than 0) - then that statement would never be true. If it were initialized to anything less than 0 then that statement would evaluate only once and x would equal  1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is a. if `x` is less than 0, then the loop will assign 1 to `x` in the first iteration. The subsequent iterations will have no effect as x will be more than 0. if `x` is already more than 0, then both approaches will not alter the value of `x`.

Comment: OK that makes sense, I think I was overthinking the problem. Thank you.

Comment: No problem. When thinking about problems like this, it's usually best to try explaining it to someone or even something. It makes you think about it more clearly. I recommend a rubber duck!

Answer (score 0):

Well if `x` has been initialized to 5 (or anything greater than 0) - then that statement would never be true. Ex:

```
int x = 3;
for (int a = 1; a < 20; a++)
    if (x < 0)
        x = a; // never reached
```

If `x` were initialized to anything less than 0 then that statement would evaluate only once and x would equal 1. Because on the second iteration:
 `if(1 < 0)` is `false` so x would never get assigned again.

```
int x = -5;
for (int a = 1; a < 20; a++)
    if (x < 0)
        x = a; // reached once only - x == 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming x is not initialized, then on the first loop, x will only ever be assigned if it is less than 0. On the first loop a = 1 and so x will be assigned to 1, and never again after that, since 1 > 0.